# How to create a custom Django form with select fields from different models?

Tags: python, django, forms

How do you make a form in Django using 3 different models as field for the form?

These are my models:

```
class User(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Team(models.Model):
    team_name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class GameCategories(models.Model):
    CATEGORIES = (
        ('Senior', 'Senior'),
        ('Middle', 'Middle'),
        ('Junior', 'Junior'),
    )

    category = models.CharField(max_length=16, choices=CATEGORIES)
```

I want to create a form using `<select><option></option></select>` with above models that would look like this:

```
<select class="form-control">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="user.id">user.first_name + user.last_name</option>
    <option value="user.id">user.first_name + user.last_name</option>
    <option value="user.id">user.first_name + user.last_name</option>
</select>
<select class="form-control">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="gamecat.id">gamecat.category</option>
    <option value="gamecat.id">gamecat.category</option>
    <option value="gamecat.id">gamecat.category</option>
</select>
<select class="form-control">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="team.id">team.team_name</option>
    <option value="team.id">team.team_name</option>
    <option value="team.id">team.team_name</option>
</select>
```

and after filling form when user click submit button I want to send to another view all values (user id, game category id, team id).

Actually I don't have idea how to do this. I guess that I should create a `ModelForm`.

Could you please help me?

Comment: Any reason why you aren't using a Django `Form`. Should the options always include all current instances of each model?

Comment: Really simple ! You must create regular form something like this: myForm(form.Form) <<<---- not model form, after that add your field manually all fields you want to show in template but and 3 others user, gamecategories, team with correct widget . it all !

Answer (score 6):

Use django forms [ModelChoiceField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield)

```
from django import forms

from .models import GameCategories, User, Team

class CustomForm(forms.Form):
    '''Form with User, Team and GameCategories'''
    user = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=User.objects.all())
    team = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Team.objects.all())
    game_category = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=GameCategories.objects.all()
    )
```

Remember if you want the selections to persist for a specific user you should make use of a `ModelForm` instead. If you are just storing it for the next request or in cookies then this solution will work.

Another thing to note is that the `__str__()` method is used as the label of the option.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, can you also tell me, when I send form to the view, and in the view I am creating an instance of form class, how can I get to the values of each model (user, team, game_category)?

Comment: You would typically validate the form and then get the data with: `user = form.cleaned_data['user']`. You should take some time to read through https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/ and https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/validation/. They might seem daunting at first but they are full of excellent content.